# show dates in lightgray color for the dates in other months using react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker package to select dates from a calendar. What I want to achieve is, if I open any month in the calendar, say August, the dates for August month should appear in black color, but the dates for the month of July and September should be displayed in lightgray color, and also the user should still be able to click it.

Currently, what I can see is that all the dates are in same color. Please refer the screenshot below -

[image]

Here, the dates from the July Month (30,31) and the dates from the September month (1,2) should be in lightgray color, and the dates for the month of August should be in black color.

Is it possible to do it using this package?